# Using git submodules with ssh authentication on Openshift

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-submodules, ssh-keys, openshift

I created a submodule (a bitbucket repo) on my openshift repo.

My current `.gitmodules` configuration:

```
[submodule "php"]
    path = php
    url = git@bitbucket.org:sgtcarneiro/repo.git
```

The problem is that after I push this code into my Openshift app i get the folling error:

```
remote: Host key verification failed.
remote: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
remote: Clone of 'git@bitbucket.org:sgtcarneiro/repo.git' into submodule path 'php' failed
```

This is expected since i didn't mention anywhere on bitbucket the pub key from the Openshift server. I already tried to check my `.ssh/` to find/edit the public key but I do not have any permissions to access that.

PS: As a workaround I am using HTTPS authentication with user and password on the submodule and is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You won't have permissions on the user's home directory, but you can store all your keys and scripts under $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR (e.g., ~/app-root/data/)  You can validate by accessing your gear/app via ssh (rhc ssh AppName) and poking around.

There are a couple of OpenShift forum threads that has some suggestions on how to run git/ssh commands from the gear/app:
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/private-git-repo-clone-on-deploy
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/gitssh-in-bashprofile-not-working-for-git-push-and-causes-error-cloning-submodules

Hope that helps.  Please feel free to post to the OpenShift Forums as well.